# All images of Android device

Tags: android

I tried to show all images of a device in my activity, something like a picture browser. Since I could not find any good tutorial, I started to develop it by myself. The problem is in cashing pictures and setting thumbnails for them. If device images are so many I can not handle them.
What is your solution?

Comment: for caching use picasso or universal image loader library

Comment: @VishalGaur you're right but using [this](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) solved all of my problems.

Comment: congratulations brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using [This](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) library?

It is my own library which I developed recently, it is best solution for what you want to do. Hope you enjoy it.